# setting up ip route to access internet via a node connected to internet directly

Tags: networking, route, iproute

I have 3 nodes connected via a router one of the machine is connected to internet via a different nic interface . Other machines cannot be connected the same way as the machine that is currently connected as they don't have only one nic interface, however I believe I can set an IP route some how.
Can anyone help me please ?

the node connected to internet 192.168.5.164 via 10.10.10.254
other nodes on same lan
192.168.5.165
and
192.168.5.166

I tried

```
ip route add default 192.168.5.164 dev eth0
```

but I still can't ping any internet site.

Node 192.168.5.164 connected to internet:

```
$ ip route show
default via 10.10.10.254 dev wlx503eaa9db3e0 proto dhcp metric 600 
default via 192.168.5.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
10.10.10.0/24 dev wlx503eaa9db3e0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.6 metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.5.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.5.164 metric 100 
blackhole 192.168.7.192/26 proto bird 
192.168.7.202 dev cali9e3ca63b6c8 scope link 
192.168.7.203 dev califd046a9218c scope link 
192.168.7.204 dev cali6e354856333 scope link
```

Second machine not connected to internet but same LAN:

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.5.164 dev eth0 
default via 192.168.5.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.5.166 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.5.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.5.166 
192.168.5.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.5.166 metric 100
```

Result of ip route get:

```
ip route get 1.1.1.1

$ ip route get 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 via 10.10.10.254 dev wlx503eaa9db3e0 src 10.10.10.6 uid 1000 
    cache
```

Comment: A router or a switch? Because it sounds like you'd be using the dual-NIC machine as a router (probably with NAT), but if you have another router in between the three machines, it just makes the matter a bit more complicated.

Comment: These three machines are connected via same router so these machines see each other. One of the machine has dual nic and connects to internet!

Comment: For this to work, two conditions must be met on the machine that is connected to the internet. First, it needs to have a route to the internet. Can you ping internet sites like 1.1.1.1 from that machine? Second, it needs to be configured for IP traffic forwarding. Check if this is the case: `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`. If the output is 0, add the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and run `sysctl -p`.

Comment: Both conditions you specified are satisfied.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the routing tables on the double-NIC machine and one of the other machines. And I forgot a third condition: 193.168.1.164 is accessible from 193.168.1.165, but I guess that this is the case as well.

Comment: @berndbausch done, first machine is also kubernetes control plane so it shows other ip addresses.

Comment: This is weird. You say that you can reach 1.1.1.1 from 192.168.5.164, yet I don't see any route on 192.168.5.164 that leads to 1.1.1.1. Furthermore, my networking skills are not sufficient to understand the second default route on 192.168.5.166.

Comment: @berndbausch you are talking about second machine. The first default is what I added to be able ping internet sites via the first machine as gateway!

Comment: How does 192.168.5.164 reach 1.1.1.1 without having a route to 1.1.1.1?

Comment: Updated missed line

Comment: This is confusing. The only default route is for DHCP. To get clarity, can you run `ip route get 1.1.1.1` on both machines?

Comment: @berndbausch I have updated the ip route now, it should make sense now. earlier it wasnt connected to internet and I wasnt aware.

Comment: I am not sure, but is the `proto dhcp` in the first default route correct? Can you try changing the route? Delete it `ip route del default via 10.10.10.254`, then add it again `ip route add default via 10.10.10.254 proto kernel metric 600`. Admittedly, though, I am not sure what the `proto dhcp` really means and if that breaks something.